# Beginner bank app withdrawal transaction

Tags: javascript

Pooja would like to withdraw `X USD` from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if `X` is a multiple of `5`, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal, the bank charges `0.50 USD`. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.

Please review my code.

```
   var x= parseInt(prompt("put the value of account balance"));
  var y=parseInt(prompt("put the value of widrawal cash "));
     const charges=0.50;

      if(y%5==0 && y<x)
    {
alert((x-y)-charges)
            }else
   {
           alert(x)
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

From a short review;

- If you are not going to change the value of a variable, use `const`, not `var`
- Avoid spelling mistakes; `widrawal` -> `withdrawal`
- The `if` statement does not take the charges in to account
- The indentation of this code is bad, please consider using a js formatter
- `alert` and `prompt` are considered only okay for the most basic exercises
- `x` and `y` are very poor names, how about `accountBalance` and `requestedAmount`?

This is my counter proposal

```
function performWithdrawal(){
  const accountBalance = parseInt(prompt("What is the value of the account balance?"));
  const requestedAmount = parseInt(prompt("How much do you wish to withdraw?"));
  const withdrawalCharges = 0.5;

  if(requestedAmount % 5 == 0 && (requestedAmount + withdrawalCharges <= accountBalance)){
    alert(`Your new bank account balance is ${accountBalance - requestedAmount - withdrawalCharges}`)
  } else {
    alert(`Your bank account balance is too low to withdraw ${requestedAmount} USD`);
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable  feedback and comment Sir

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that the amounts have to be integers. By using `parseInt()`, you end up truncating the decimal portion of the input, which is wrong.

Comment: I am not sure how any non-integer amount can be a multiple of 5? Hmm, your point stands for the bank balance.

Comment: @konijn That is a problem, though. If a user asks to withdraw $5.99, it thinks you want to withdraw $5 and allows it.

Comment: We should move to chat, but I would rather get 5 dollars instead of a message that it has to be a multiple of 5, then re-enter 5, and then finally get 5 dollars ;)

Comment: @konijn  But what if you really needed $5.99?  Now you have $5 and are $.99 short; if you withdraw another $5, it costs you $.50 more.  But if you receive "needs to be a multiple of 5", you can enter $10 and have $4.01 extra.  Alternately, a better UI might be to reply, "Needs to be a multiple of $5; do you want to withdraw $10?  (Y/N)" which would streamline that interaction while still being accurate.  Or offer more choices:  $5 (rounded down); $10 (rounded up); something else.